# Show and hide images in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have some images.The images are one above the other and depending on the situation I have to show one or the other, but my process does not work.
this is the code

```
    AddHTMLToCurrentSlide('<div id="slide14_gc"></div>');
AddHTMLToCurrentSlide('<div classe="drag-x" id="slide14_gp"></div>');
AddHTMLToCurrentSlide('<div id="slide14_empty"></div>');
AddHTMLToCurrentSlide('<div id="slide14_25mg"></div>');
AddHTMLToCurrentSlide('<div id="slide14_50mg"></div>');


     $(function () {

    $("#slide14_gc").hide(); //here work
    $("#slide14_gp").show();

    $("#slide14_gc").draggable({
    handle:"#slide14_gc",
    containment: [50,105,625,48],
    axis: "x"
    });

    $("#slide14_gp").draggable({
    handle:"#slide14_gc",
    containment: [50,105,625,48],
    axis: "x"
    });





     var part =parseInt($('#slide14_gc').css('left'));
     var maxlungh =parseInt($('#slide14_gc').css('width'));
     var arr = parseInt(part) + parseInt(maxlungh); 
     var pos =$("#slide14_gc").position();

     if(pos == part){
         $("#slide14_gc").hide();
         $("#slide14_gp").show();
        $("#slide14_empty").show(); //not show
        $("#slide14_25mg").hide(); //not hide
        $("#slide14_50mg").hide(); //not hide
     }

     if(pos>part && pos<265){
         $("#slide14_gc").show();
        $("#slide14_gp").hide();
        $("#slide14_empty").hide(); //not hide
        $("#slide14_25mg").show(); //not show
        $("#slide14_50mg").hide(); //not hide

     }

     if(pos>265 && pose<arr){
        $("#slide14_empty").hide(); //not hide
        $("#slide14_25mg").hide();  //not hide
        $("#slide14_50mg").show();  //not show
     }





});
```

Comment: Questions like this are the ones which receive less or cero answers. Be more concrete. Add a jsfiddle, try something, post less code...

Comment: "Here's my code, fix it for me". No. Have a downvote.

Comment: I just wanted a suggestion because I can not find the error. The javascript I am learning now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try create new css class, and add or remove them:

```
.hide {
  display: none!important;
}


$("#slide14_25mg").addClass("hide"); 
$("#slide14_50mg").removeClass("hide");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your script is that [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)'s [`position`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) method doesn't return an int. Quoting the jQuery's docs:

> Returns an object containing the properties top and left.

You're comparing `pos` which is an object with an integer, so none of the if blocks are executed (as none of the conditions are met).